# Android WebView Jsoup

Tags: android, webview, jsoup

I'm working on an app in which I would like to display my website but with less div elements.

In this example code, I used the website of stackoverflow.com and have tried to hide the div class hmenus (buttons at the top of the main website).

After running the code, I get a blank / white webview. What I have tried is to make the String html final and call it afterwards to set my final url for the webview.

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.File;

public class MyCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(File... params) {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/").get();
    Elements ele = doc.select(":not(#hmenus)");        // ->>>>> Jsoup html
    final String html = ele.toString();

}}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private WebView WebView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView = (WebView) findViewById(webView);
        WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        final String mime = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "utf-8";
        WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                // ->>>>>>   Change the website --->>> insert call html value
                WebView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I call the value of html `final String html = ele.toString();` and cast it to `WebView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `AsyncTask` the right way. You should read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Declare the `AsyncTask` and implement the `doInBackground` for getting the web page and `onPostExecute` for displaying the result when it is ready:

```
private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

// This is run in a background thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://stackoverflow.com/")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0")
                    .get();
            Elements ele = doc.select("#hmenus");
            html = ele.toString();
            return html;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("APP", e.toString());
        }            
        return "error";
    }

    // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("APP", "1");
        WebView.loadData(result, mime, encoding);            
    }
}
```

As for the `MainActivity`, it must invoke the `AsyuncTask`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView WebView;
    String html = "Loading...";
    final String mime = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "utf-8";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //Display "Loading..." message while waiting
        WebView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);
        //Invoke the AsyncTask
        new GetData().execute();
    }
}
```

Don't forget the `internet-permission` at your manifest.

Comment: I have made chages to the code you suggested, sounds obvious. But it does not fix my initial problem - which is calling the actual html value is set

Comment: I have implemented your suggested changes. Have updated my first post. I am still at that spot where I do not get the - final String html = ele.toString(); - in my WebView.loadData(html,mime,encoding);

Comment: Did I get it right, it should work with the code you have shared? The build is successfull but I get different errors after trying to launch it: -Error:(17, 9) error: modifier private not allowed here (private class GetData)'
-Error:(27, 13) error: cannot assign a value to final variable html ( html = ele.toString();)'

Comment: 1. The `GetData` should be inside the `MainActivity`, right after `onCreate`. 2. Don't define `html` as `final`.